# Last activity time of HWND - get the last active hwnd

Tags: winapi

Edit: Thanks to guys below I learned that windows doesn't have this last activity info. So I'll make this question more precise. I have a list of HWNDs and I want the one that was more recently active. I read of `GetLastActivePopup` but it seems to not give me the right one, it seems to always give me the same hwnd i pass to it. Is this because `popup` is different from `hwnd`?

Old question was this:

> I have a list of HWNDs.
>
> I actually used `EnumWindowsProc`, `EnumWindows`, and `EnumChildWindows` to get a list of all windows. I grouped them by PID. (I got PID with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`). I would like to sort the windows in each each group by last focus time. How can I get the info of when the window was last focused?
>
> In X11 (Unix/Linux) we have this property called `_NET_WM_USER_TIME` on windows. Is there something similar like this on Windows HWNDs?

Thanks

Comment: I've never come across such a thing in Windows, I think you would have to keep track of this yourself using hooks etc.

Comment: Windows does not keep track of this information.

Comment: Aw dang, any way to get just the most recent hwnd? I saw a function `GetLastActivePopup` but its not returning me the right window, or im doing something wrong. All i really need is just the last active window, i think the problem is `window` differs from `popup`, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Why do you want this information?

Comment: I need to focus the last used window. Users in my addon click on a profile. If it is running, rather then launch it, it focuses the most recently focused window. (i got it in linux and mac but having hard time in windows :( ) how i did it for other os: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/60aab0a96f060240614f

Comment: Guess, one option is to use SetWindowsHookEx to set up hooks and intercept WM_ACTIVATE for these windows

Comment: Thanks man that's a good idea, but that won't work for me :(

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I'm trying to `SetForegroundWindow` on the `HWND` in my array that was most recently focused by the user. Thanks I really appreciate your question to dig deeper into my situation.

Comment: Hey guys, I thought about this. And the alt+tab menu holds the windows in order of last used. Any way to see which one of the HWND in my array occurs first in the alt+tab menu, then I will focus that HWND. What do you think?

Comment: I think I just asked an xy quesiton execused that please (re: hwnds in order of alt tab menu) Ill create new topic for it.

Comment: The Alt+ Tab window does not use order of last used.

Comment: Oh dang, what does it use?

Comment: Is it possible to sort these by z-order? Without using GetNextWindow/GetWindow (this seems to get stuck in an infinite loop for me)?