# HWNDs of Alt+Tab Menu (In Order)

Tags: winapi

I got an xy question situation so excuse that please ([Last activity time of HWND - get the last active hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081144/last-activity-time-of-hwnd-get-the-last-active-hwnd)). This topic fixes that.

I need to get an array of the HWNDs, in order as they show, of the alt+tab menu.

I was thinking of doing this: Use [MSDN :: GetAltTabInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I think i provide an HWND too and it spits back:

```
typedef struct tagALTTABINFO {
  DWORD cbSize;
  int   cItems;
  int   cColumns;
  int   cRows;
  int   iColFocus;
  int   iRowFocus;
  int   cxItem;
  int   cyItem;
  POINT ptStart;
} ALTTABINFO, *PALTTABINFO, *LPALTTABINFO;
```

Where cxItem and cyItem give the location of the HWND in the alt tab menu?

Is this how that works? Is this the way I should take? I have to know an HWND first then test for its location in alt+tab menu with this function above?

Or is there some way to list out the HWNDs in order of the alt+tab menu?

Comment: Reading the documentation for `ALTTABINFO`, it's very clear that is not how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GetTopWindow`/`GetNextWindow` to enumerate through the desktop's children in Z order, and then test the style to see if it's eligible to be in the alt+tab list. Something like:

```
HWND child = GetTopWindow(NULL);
LONG mask = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION;

while (child != NULL)
{
    LONG style = GetWindowLong(child, GWL_STYLE);

    if ((style & mask) == mask)
    {
        // do something with child.
    }

    child = GetNextWindow(child, GW_HWNDNEXT);
}
```

Comment: I guess you have to rule out WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW too

Comment: Raymond Chen had a blog post a while ago on the rules for Alt+Tab inclusion, I seem to remember they were different on every version of Windows.

Comment: Thanks Cory and @JonathanPotter thanks ill look up that blog post for the different versions of windows.

Comment: Is there anyway to do like IPC between the alt+tab hwnd to figure out what its listing?

Comment: Holy heck I just used the GetNextWindow and GetWindow thing and only testing GetWindowLong for WS_VISIBLE. And even if minimized the hwnd shows up before the maximized window. (unlike in alt tab menu) So that works just like get most recent window! Is this expected behavior? Can I rely on this assumption for XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 8.1?

Comment: Update: That above is true for Win8.1. On WinXP there are some quirks: **1** if all windows minimized: it focuses the window that was FIRST minimized
**2** if last focused window was minimized, it will focus the first non-minimized that had most recent focus

Comment: Update: Just test Win7. So the z-order works for most recent window even with minimized windows, only for Win8.1. For Win7 it has same quirks as WinXP, im guessting win vista is same as its between 7 and xp.

Comment: Hi @JonathanPotter can you please link me to that blog post you mentioned I can't find it, i found this but it wasnt exactly what I was looking for: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.windowsconfidential.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is analysis on differetn Windows versions of the code by @CoryNelson (huge thanks to him for the help)

### behavior research via physical testing:

*NOTE learned that when minimized `hwnd` has `WS_ICONIC` and `WS_MINIMIZED` flags while still having the `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_VISIBLE` flags*

#### win81:

- works as expected, it focuses the most recently used window EVEN IF minmized

#### win7 and winxp:

- focused browser, minimized, so last focus was browser. scratch is currently non-minimized. test result :: clicked focus most rec win profilist : it focuses scratch, and the hwnd of browser does not occur before the hwnd of scratch (i was hoping it would occur before scratch but would have WS_MINIMIZED-or-something and just be missing WS_VISIBLE or something)

  ```
  //hwnds
  0x240de4 //scratch
  0x110e30 //browser
  ```

  - *FIX: i dont know how to fix this one yet, anyone any ideas other than hooking? ill keep thinking, mainly posting this here for myself, but if anyone wants to apply thoughts more then welcome!!*
- if all windows minimized: it focuses the window that was FIRST minimized

  - *FIX: this one i can fix by seeing if the first hwnd found with WS_VISIBLE and WS_CAPTION has minimized flags, if it does then keep going till it finds the last WS_VISIBLE and WS_CAPTION one (im pretty sure all the ones after it will have the minimized flags, really very sure as it looks like when minimize it gets thrown to end [right in alt+tab menu] of array (unlike when focus non-minimized it gets moved to top of array [left in alt tab]))*

### GUESSES as i cant physically test these

#### win8

- im guessing win8 behaves as win81

#### winvista

- im guessing winVist behaves as winxp and win7 as its in between