# OS X Programmatically Click Menu Item of Dock Menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

This is my dock menu:
[image]

I would like to programmatically click that button "Show Most Recent Window". Can this programmatically be done using Cocoa or CoreFoundation?

I know the PID the dock item is associated with.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this, although generally you can easily set an `AppleScript` or `oascript` that can handle this. Basically it involves using `AXRaise`, which essentially calls on the function to raise the frontmost window of the application specified.

**Code:**

```
set mostrecentWindow to "mostrecentWindow"
set theApplication to "Safari"
tell application "System Events"
    if exists process theApplication then
        --raise frontmost window
        tell process theApplication
            set frontmost to true
            perform action "AXRaise" of (windows whose title is mostrecentWindow)
        end tell
    else if not (exists process theApplication) then
        --display alert
        display alert "Warning: process " & theApplication & " is not running"
    end if
end tell
```

The above example checks whether or not the process Safari is running, and if it is then raise it's most recent (or frontmost) window to the foreground; otherwise show a warning that the process is not running.

Comment: Thank you for the aewsome example. This is awesome even better then simulating click on the dock items menu item. I actually prefer not having to simulate click on the dock items menu item. However `AXRaise` requires "Assistive Mode" turned on huh? Can you please share a method that doesn't need assistive movde. I really appreciate it. I don't use a Mac so I don't know anything about it :( , but I have awesome Mac users, and lots of them, so need to support them please.

Comment: Well, I figured out a method without enabling assistive devices, but I really think it's way too unpredictable to be something that I would recommend anyone using, especially for anything you might distribute; I'll gladly share the info though if you're interested.

Comment: Yes please man I really appreciate it!!! Can you please explain the unpredictabilities of it. I will definitely work on it by asking around I go to these code meetups. Thanks very much man!

Comment: Since it doesn't require the assistive devices enabled it uses only internals of window items (not windows). This is how it gets around the need to use it, although the problem is that every application sets it's windows up differently - meaning the items are also different and change often. I didn't have any issues using it with Safari, but with Firefox some very strange things happened, including some piece of a window or box that gets corrupted somehow and sticks in one spot.

Comment: The weirdness usually happens if the window is minimized and you run the script — I'm not sure if anyone has tried a method such as this, and it's probably not the best way of doing things, so maybe someone can expand upon it. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebe9af62a4162713f5fe).

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing that! The minimized window behavior is funkiness I encountered on pre Windows 8 as well! Eventaully found a work around it :) this is the pre Win8 funk: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26190771/1828637

Comment: I was curious, doing `set frontmost to true` seems to bring it to the front, why do we bother with `AXRaise`? Edit: ah i see when i full screened a window and moved it to side while leaving one popup in the main desktop, when i did set frontmost it made it go to the popup, not the full screened window which was most recent, is this true? also how do i get title of most recent window in above we are setting it to string `mostrecetnWindow` which isnt correct no?

Comment: I also found this guy here trying to fix weirdness, I couldn't get past some bugs but do you think it would help solve our weirdness: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24636884/3791822

Comment: `AXRaise` is useful if the window is minimized or behind other windows that might have focus. In addition you have more control over exactly which window(s) you want to control. All of the scripts listed on that example you posted require assistive devices be enabled. Setting the title of the window is really more or less just an alias to whatever window that happens to be. You can specifically call upon a particular window by it's name though if you know what it will be.

Comment: Hey man I decided to go with AXRaise method as a backup, but it's not unminimizing the most recent window. I think this is because I don't have the title. Any way to get the title of the most recent window?

Comment: Yes there are several ways, this one is pretty reliable: `tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true) *(linebreak)* set theWindow to value of attribute "AXTitle" *(linebreak)* end tell`

Comment: Thanks for such a fast reply Ill test it out! That way looks like it doesnt need Accessibility because its just reading properties huh?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a task that can be done using [GUI Scripting](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html) using [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/applescript/).

Comment: Thanks Simon for the fast reply. I was wondering if possible to not use AppleScript because I don't think I can run AppleScript from my C code :(

Comment: Hmm, there is the [NSAppleScript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsapplescript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class but I'm not sure how to use that in C.

Comment: Ah interesting I'll research that, but it looks like it needs "Assistive Mode" enabled :(

Comment: @Noitidart, what's wrong with having assitive mode enabled? It's quite typical on OS X, especially if you want to use many AppleScripts.

Comment: My target audience doesn't guarantee if they have it on or not :( And I can't ask them to turn it on :(